# How to make Response.Write Display special character like "<",">"

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, html-escape-characters, response.write

I want to use Response.Write to display some text on the screen using ASP.NET
I created a variable

```
String s = "There is some <hidden text> which is not visible";
Response.Write(s);
```

What I found is when the browser only display "There is some which is not visible"
any text written in between symbols '<'......'>' is neglected by the browser.

How can I display entire text?

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [HTML Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Server.HtmlEncode("There is some <hidden text> which is not visible");
```

Comment: thanks @Emad This also worked when i used it as
    Response.Write(Server.HtmlEncode("There is some <hidden text> which is not visible");)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
String s = @"There is some <hidden text> which is not visible";
Response.Write(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with C# so this might not work, but you can escape the `<` and `>` by using html escape characters.

`&#60;` for `<`

`&#62;` for `>`

So maybe try...

```
String s = "There is some &#60;hidden text&#62; which is not visible";
```

Comment: Might have to escape the semicolon in C# somehow.

Comment: Perfect this worked :-) Using escape sequence character '/' before the  special character was also not working